# Tcl: processing variables in a list

Tags: loops, tcl

Maybe this is pretty stupid, but I really can't find a soulution. I created two variables and want to transform them into lists.
This commands are tool specific, but they work the way I want:

```
redirect max_transition {report_constraint -view $pargs(-scenario) -drv_violation_type {max_transition} -all_violators} -variable
redirect max_capacitance {report_constraint -view $pargs(-scenario) -drv_violation_type {max_capacitance} -all_violators} -variable
```

Now I want to create tcl lists out of them. I could use a loop, because the data has the same structure.

```
set reports {$max_transition $max_capacitance}
set report_length [llength $reports]

for {set i 0} {$i < $report_length} {incr i} { 
    set tns_value 0
        set max_wns 0
    set vios 0

    set report [lindex $reports $i]
    puts $report

    # remove all uneccessary white spaces
    set no_space [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $report]

    # insert a new line for every path
    set insert_lines [string map {" U_" \nU_} $no_space]

    # create list out of result reports
    set report_list [split $insert_lines "\n"]

    if {[llength $report_list] > 1} {
        for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $report_list]} {incr i} {
            # get value of violation
            set slack [lindex [split [lindex $report_list $i] " "] 3]

            set tns_value [expr $tns_value + $slack]
            if {$vios == 0} {set max_wns $slack}
            incr vios 
        }
    }
    # write out values
    puts "$pargs(-scenario), $report, $max_wns, $tns_value, $vios"
}
```

But this does not work out. The loop just puts out the variable's names (because of "puts $report") but not its content.
If I do it without a loop (so for each variable the same code consecutively), I get the lists I want.
So how can I process these variables as a whole in a loop?

Comment: The first line sets `reports` to exactly the list of `$max_transition` and `$max_capacitance`, i.e. two strings, each beginning with a dollar sign. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hmm... no. In fact I just want to point to the beginning (or the store location) of those variables I created above. If I use foreach and list those two variables, those will be interpreted just as stings but not as lists itself.

Comment: voting to close. I think this question has no value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the below loop variable `i`, it is overriding variable value of outer-loop. Try changing inner-loop variable to `j`.

```
    for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $report_list]} {incr i} {
        # get value of violation
        set slack [lindex [split [lindex $report_list $i] " "] 3]

        set tns_value [expr $tns_value + $slack]
        if {$vios == 0} {set max_wns $slack}
        incr vios 
    }
```

Comment: Yeah... this was wrong indeed. But this does not solve the problem.  I would expect, that the command "puts $report" will print the value of the variable I created above the loop. Instead it just prints the name of the variable in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to write an answer for this since so much is unknown. To begin with, you should probably change to assignment by `list` and a `foreach` loop like this:

```
set reports [list $max_transition $max_capacitance]

foreach report $reports {
```

Since you don't really need to use a `for` loop here, it makes sense to simplify it. Please comment and I will iteratively improve the answer if I can.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've finally managed to get it working. I've created an array for the lists:
 redirect report_array(max_transition) {report_constraint -view $pargs(-scenario) -drv_violation_type {max_transition} -all_violators} -variable
 redirect report_array(max_capacitance) {report_constraint -view $pargs(-scenario) -drv_violation_type {max_capacitance} -all_violators} -variable
And created a foreach loop over the indices:
 foreach report {max_transition max_capacitance} {

Inside I only have to change the first set:
set no_space [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $report_array($report)